# Opening web projects with Yeoman scafolding in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, angularjs, yeoman

In our Angular JS project , we are currently using Yeoman as the scaffolding tool and Web storm 8.0 as the IDE... We want to change our IDE to Eclipse Luna....  I could not find any good article on how to open Yeoman scafolded angular JS projects in Eclipse... Can any one point me in the right direction

Regards
Sabarish

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started.
When you create project go with Static Web Project or (as I did) General -> Project and just copy all your files to the project folder.